# Cmake и box2d

Tags: cmake, c++

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь запустить движек box2d. Вылезают некие неведомые ошибки. Где-то начитал, что ошибки можно устранить с помощью cmake... Но я не понял что такое этот cmake и как с его помощью "переработать" проект? Пока ничего не получилось...
Спасибо.

Comment: Нужны детали: как собираете? что за ошибки вылазят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в библиотеке найти файл CMakeList.txt и открыть его в IDE
а потом сделать сборку

должно получиться. там есть тестовый проект его тоже можете собрать

Comment: Спасибо, получилось) Еще давно сделал)